# C++ Create callback from C++/CLI to C++

Tags: c++, events, callback, c++-cli, mixed-mode

Hello for my project i have the "main" dll non cli in a process.
Then i have multiples instance of c# dll which embed a CLI dll.
From c# i can add a "EventHandler" to the cli.

Now the tricky part.
I want the CLI to invoke the "main" dll, send to it a function pointer to callback so the cli can then raise events in c# using custom class defined inthe CLI. and since i have multiples instance of that c#/cli script inside my process i cant use dllimport ( or atleast i dont think it will invoke in all dll's )

However here is my issue today, i am not sure how to declare the function pointers and type def here is what i have so far:

CLI Wrapper script:

```
typedef void(__stdcall CallbackFunctionPtr)(Native::Object);
typedef void(__stdcall *CallbackFunction)(CallbackFunctionPtr*);
void ObjectManagerWrapper::AddObjectCreatedHandler(System::EventHandler^ callBackEvent)
{
     OnObjectCreatedEvent += callBackEvent;
     HINSTANCE hDLL = LoadLibrary("Main.dll");
     if (hDLL == NULL) {
     }
     else {
          CallbackFunction start = (CallbackFunction)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "AddObjectCreatedCallback");

          start(&ObjectManagerWrapper::OnObjectCreated);
     }
     FreeLibrary(hDLL);
}
static void OnObjectCreated(Native::Object* obj)
{
    AObject^ aobj = gcnew AObject();

    OnObjectCreatedEvent(aobj, gcnew System::EventArgs());
}
```

However as you may guess this doesnt work.
I am not sure how can i send the pointer to my function OnObjectCreated.

And in the "Main" dll here is the code:

```
typedef void(__stdcall * ObjectCallbackPtr)(Native::Object* obj);
ObjectCallbackPtr(myObj);
```